# How to cut big file at bof - C/Linux

Tags: c, linux, file

I'm working on one software for streaming server and somehow I have to implement replay function, so that users can view live stream for e.g. 24h in past. Storing stream is not problem, I could just append to file and all is good, but that file will be larger and larger. So I have to cut it at begin, maybe each hour. Now, I'm completely out of idea how to do that. I need some fast solution, because I assume that file for 24h will be around 50GB. Any ideas? Is fallocate() solution? Thanks in advance. (Sorry for my English)

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: As a solution just determine amount of data that needed to be cut off and cut it with `ftruncate`

Comment: I didn't try anything until now. ftruncate will cut file at eof, but I need to cut at bof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Linux 3.15 or higher, and an ext4 filesystem, you can do it using [`fallocate()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html):

Example:

```
fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE, 0, 100*1024*1024);
```

will cut off the first 100 MB of the file.

Comment: I'm running 2.6.32 here on my PC and in office I have 3.13 on few servers. Sh*t!

Comment: @IgorPejašinović Time to upgrade?

Comment: I have update one server to 3.15 kernel, but seems like fallocate don't work.

Comment: Hmm.. try `lsattr filename` to see if the `e` bit (extent) bit is set.  If it is not set, try `chattr +e filename` to set the `e` bit.  There is also an `fallocate` linux command.  You can try that first on your files to see if that works.  Note that you can only truncate amounts that are multiples of your filesystem's block size.  `fallocate -c -o 0 -l 16384 filename`.

Comment: Seems like I must update my ubuntu server 14.04 to 14.10. Then I'll try fallocate. Looks like exactly solution which I need.

Comment: Just to say, I'm very happy with `fallocate()`. Work flawless.